# What is the number N represented in floating point by the binary string of 32 bits whose hexadecimal representation is 8A000000?

Tags: floating-point

What is the number N represented in floating point by the binary string of 32 bits whose hexadecimal representation is 8A000000?

Please help me. How can I find it?

Comment: By finding out what binary representation is used, finding the specification for it, and working from there

Comment: [Floating-point converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Comment: Same question as in your deleted question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814597/what-is-the-number-n-represented-in-floating-point-by-the-binary-string-of-32): What are the parameters of your floating point system?

Answer (score -1):

The number is `-6.162976e-33`.

I used the following code in c to find it out:

```
int a[1] = {0x8A000000};
float* p = a;

printf("%e\n", p[0]);
```

The trick here is that you can only create integer from hexa values, and then I cast the pointer to float pointer and print the dereferenced value.

A more simple way is to google for "float from hex converter" and past your number into the first result.

Comment: The behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard because it violates the anti-aliasing rule (C 2011 [N1570] 6.5 7). Proper ways to reinterpret an object representation are by using a union (as with `printf("%g\n", (union { uint32_t u; float f; }) { 0x8a000000 } .f);`) or by copying the bytes from one object into another (as with `uint32_t u = 0x8A000000; float f; memcpy(&f, &u, sizeof f);`. The behavior is also undefined because it causes integer overflow (if `int` is 32 bits). A type such as `uint32_t` ought to be used, assuming `float` is 32 bits.